# Lines between points by id

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with points on a 2-dimensional plane:

```
 index          x          y
0       0  -0.032836  49.268820
1       0   4.160005  49.268820
2       0   4.105928  68.330440
3       0  -0.062953  68.342125
4       1   4.166139  49.269398
5       1   8.497650  49.278310
6       1   8.592334  68.336560
7       1   4.041361  68.336560
8       2   8.426349  49.278890
9       2  13.480260  49.278890
10      2  13.446286  68.336560
11      2   8.467557  68.336560
12      3  13.438516  49.278374
13      3  17.356792  49.287285
14      3  17.378400  68.338240
15      3  13.382163  68.333786
16      4  17.295988  49.289800
17      4  21.418156  49.289800
18      4  21.336264  67.359630
19      4  17.313816  67.359630
```

and I've been trying to find a way to draw lines between the `(x,y)` coordinates for each `index`. The resulting plot should be closed rectangles.

Now, I've tried to approach this by defining series:

```
x = df['x']
y = df['y']
```

and then

```
index_l = df.index.tolist()
for i in index_l:
    plt.plot([df.x[i],df.y[i]])
```

This doesn't work at all. Any idea on how to proceed. A note: ideally, I would like to have a rectangle, but if doing this by even connecting diagonally is easier, I can live with it.

Thankful for any hints or solutions.

Comment: You're saying you declared two new variables, `x` and `y`, and done nothing with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the `index` and then for `x, y` values of each group, append the first row to the end so that `plt.plot` plots a closed rectangle:

```
for idx, points in df.groupby("index")[["x", "y"]]:
    points_to_plot = points.append(points.iloc[0])
    plt.plot(points_to_plot.x, points_to_plot.y)
```

to get [this plot](https://www.hizliresim.com/38uegyc)

Comment: Great answer!! Thanks a lot!